# If I send request with PUT, and server return valid page with 403 status. This is correct work?

Tags: http, webserver

I send PUT. Server returned 301 status to valid http-address(!), but next response 403 status to hhtp-address. If I copy/paste this address all works correct. Please, say me: this is correct response from server or no?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are doing and moreover what is expected - which means one cannot say if this is correct. But a PUT resulting in a 301 will likely be followed by a GET to the new location given in the response and not another PUT, so this could explain the different responses. Still, I think that with the current content this is not a question about information security, i.e. off-topic here.

Comment: No! PUT -> again PUT -> http-page with 403 status. I think this is not correct response, yes?

Comment: Nothing in the question indicates what the correct response should be. 403 is a perfectly valid HTTP response. Again, it is unclear what really is done and what  is expected (and why) and it is also off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

From [HTTP/1.1 standards](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6), 301 response from a PUT request means the origin server wants the request to be made to the redirected URI. It's perfectly valid.

403 response means you don't have access to the URI. I think you did something wrong while sending the request.